# Why can "with" not be followed by the -ing form of verbs in manner adverbials?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

As we know, one way to construct a manner adverbial is using the **-ing** form of verbs after prepositions. However, it seems that the preposition **with** shows different behavior. To clarify what I mean, let us look at the following examples, using the similar preparation *without*:

> You can answer me *without* a smile.
>
> You can answer me *without* smiling.

But, the second example sentence in the following is incorrect:

> You can answer me *with* a smile.
>
> *You can answer me *with* smiling.

Regarding the similarity in the above examples, I wonder why it is ungrammatical **with** being followed by the **-ing** form of verbs in such a structure.

Comment: "You can answer me with smiling" could be grammatically correct if smiling is a valid answer, for example: "You can answer me with smiling to signify you want to continue"

Comment: @flumperious in that case, the idiomatic preposition would be "by": "you can answer me **by** smiling."

Comment: As a counterexample, I consider this grammatical (though I can’t articulate why): “It’s never too late to fall in love with swimming.”

Comment: @thehole Regarding your literally true comment, I edited this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use a different verb, as you could interpret the sentence to mean that the smile *is* the answer, as @flumperious pointed out. ["Service with a smile"](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/service_with_a_smile) is an advertising slogan that has morphed into an exhortation used by mid-level managers addressing their employees.

> [Perform] service without a smile
> [Perform] service without smiling

In the first example we are describing a *thing* that the person performing the service lacks (a smile), while in the second case we are describing an *action* that the person performing the service is not taking (smiling).

> [Perform] service with a smile
> [Perform] *service with smiling

Again, the first phrase describes a thing while the second describes an action. It is not idiomatic to say someone does a thing "with + participle" (with laughing, with running, with talking on the phone, etc). Instead we use **while**:

> [Perform] service while smiling

I am not sure why it is the case that "without" can be used for both situations while "with" can only be used for the one. It's just one of those rules that native speakers will understand by virtue of growing up with the language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I receive no other answer in some days, I will accept this answer, regarding its last sentence.